# Working with missing values in Deedle Time Series in F# (1)

Tags: f#, missing-data, deedle

here is a small example where I want to deal with missing values on custom functions on series.

suppose that i have obtained a series

```
 series4;;
 val it : Series<int,int opt> =
 1 -> 1         
 2 -> 2         
 3 -> 3         
 4 -> <missing>
```

for example, this way:

```
 let series1 = Series.ofObservations [(1,1);(2,2);(3,3)]
 let series2 = Series.ofObservations [(1,2);(2,2);(3,1);(4,4)]

 let series3 = series1.Zip(series2,JoinKind.Outer);;
 let series4 = series3 |> Series.mapValues fst
```

Then if i do,

```
 Series.mapAll (fun v -> match v with
                             | Some a -> (a>1)
                             | _-> false) series4
```

that fails with

> System.Exception: Operation could not be completed due to earlier
>   error  The type 'int option' does not match the type 'int opt'. See
>   also input.fsx(4,42)-(4,49). at 4,42

while i would like the result to be

```
val it : Series<int,bool opt> =
     1 -> false        
     2 -> true         
     3 -> true         
     4 -> false
```

even better would be to able to get a result like

```
val it : Series<int,int opt> =
     1 -> false         
     2 -> true         
     3 -> true         
     4 -> <missing>
```

what would be the right syntax there ? ideally if there is a `<missing>` value, i would like a `<missing>` value for the same key in the new series

basically i need to do pattern matching on `int opt` type

Bonus question: is there are vectorized operator in Deedle for some usual operators such like ">" ? 
(series1 > series2) when both series have the same key types would return a new series of boolean (option ?)type

thanks

Comment: `Series.mapAll` seems to accept a function that returns `'a option`, so I think that you need to return `Some (a>1)` and `Some false` in your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
let series5 =
    series4
    |> Series.mapValues(OptionalValue.map(fun x -> x > 1))
```

You can read about module `OptionalValue` in the [documentation](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/reference/deedle-optionalvaluemodule.html)