# Working with missing values in Deedle Time Series in F# (2)

Tags: filter, f#, series, missing-data, deedle

This question is related to 
[Working with missing values in Deedle Time Series in F# (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021249/working-with-missing-values-in-deedle-time-series-in-f-1)

Suppose i have a `Series<'K,'T opt>` with some missing values

For example i have obtained a series

```
 series4;;
 val it : Series<int,int opt> =
 1 -> 1         
 2 -> 2         
 3 -> 3         
 4 -> <missing>
```

I could have got it this way:

```
 let series1 = Series.ofObservations [(1,1);(2,2);(3,3)]
 let series2 = Series.ofObservations [(1,2);(2,2);(3,1);(4,4)]

 let series3 = series1.Zip(series2,JoinKind.Outer);;
 let series4 = series3 |> Series.mapValues fst
```

However, in Deedle if you do

```
let series1_plus_2 = series1+series2

val series1_plus_2 : Series<int,int> =
1 -> 3         
2 -> 4         
3 -> 4         
4 -> <missing>
```

you can see that the type `Series<int,int>` also naturally allows for missing values. And this seems the natural way to use functions in Deedle handling missing values

So my question is given series4 of type `Series<int,int opt>`, how do i get back a series with the "same" values but a type `Series<int,int>` ????

Notably, strange things are happening

for example, `Series.dropMissing` has not the expected behaviour when applied to series4

```
Series.dropMissing series4;;
 val it : Series<int,int opt> =
 1 -> 1         
 2 -> 2         
 3 -> 3         
 4 -> <missing>
```

its NOT dropping the missing value !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem here is that `int opt` is not Deedle standard way to handle missing values. Value in `series4` is not missing, but it have value `OptionalValue.Missing`. You can convert `Series<int, int opt>` to `Series<int, int>` for example this way:

`let series4' = series4 |> Series.mapAll (fun _ v -> v |> Option.bind OptionalValue.asOption)`